# Applying a missing value distribution of a Dataframe to a subset of the Dataframe: Needs to be faster

Tags: python, pandas, performance, dataframe

I have a large pandas Dataframe (20k rows).  Mocking up some data:

```
columns = [chr(i) for i in range(ord('a'),ord('z')+1)]
df = pd.DataFrame(np.random.randint(0,100,size=(20000, 26)), columns=columns)

for col in df.columns:
    df.loc[df.sample(frac=0.4).index, col] = np.nan
```

In this Dataframe some of the columns might contain missing values indicated with NaN.  I need to filter out missing values for a single column of and return a new Dataframe that has no missing values in that column:

```
col_name = "a"
dframe = df.copy()
df_col = dframe[~dframe[col_name].isnull()]
```

Now df_col still may have missing values in the other columns of the subset.  But what I have lost is when missing values co-occur with what I filtered out.  So if col_name is "A" it might be that "D" is usually missing when "A" is missing.  Now it appears that "D" is always present in df_col.

I want to take the missing distribution from dframe and randomly sample from df_col to simulate the missing values.  By missing distribution I mean combinations of column names that have NaN values and their proportions:

```
{
["A", "E", "G"]: 0.24,
["G", "Z"]: 0.01,
["G"]: 0.32,
...,
["R", "M"]: 0.09
}
```

I have functions that do this but they are too slow for my needs:

```
from typing import List, Dict
import pandas as pd
import numpy as np

def get_freq_dict(df: pd.DataFrame) -> Dict[str, float]:
    num_samples = df.shape[0]
    col_names = df.columns
    list_of_lists = df.apply(lambda row: [i for i in col_names if np.isnan(row[i])], axis=1).tolist()
    output = {}
    for lis in list_of_lists:
        output.setdefault(tuple(lis), list()).append(1)
    for a, b in output.items():
        output[a] = sum(b) / float(num_samples)
    return output

def add_in_missingness(df_col, freq_dist) -> pd.DataFrame:
    sample_list = []
    df_m = df_col.copy()
    for key in freq_dist:
        sample = df_m.sample(frac=freq_dist[key], replace=False, random_state=1)

        # remove idx from options
        blacklist = list(sample.index)
        df_m = df_m[~df_m.index.isin(blacklist)]

        col_names = list(key)
        sample[col_names] = np.NaN
        sample_list.append(sample)
    df_col = pd.concat(sample_list)
    return df_col
```

running it

```
%%time
import time
freq_dist = get_freq_dict(df)
df_ = add_in_missingness(df_col, freq_dist)
```

Seems to work but it takes far too long for my purposes:

```
CPU times: user 1min 1s, sys: 439 ms, total: 1min 1s
Wall time: 1min 1s
```

I need help making these function efficient.  Any ideas?

Comment: Do you just want `df["col"].fillna(df["col"].sample(1).iloc[0])`?

Comment: No.  I need to apply the missing value distribution from the unfiltered Dataframe to the filtered Dataframe.

Comment: I think `fillna`&`sample` will be able to accomplish this. If necessary just add weights to sample